# SSRS Visual Studio Report Parameter Issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

There is a SQL report built - with Visual studio SSRS Report on the front end.

There are default values set in the SSRS report for the 5 parameters for testing - in 4 out of 5 cases those defaults don't get pushed into the report. However in the case of 1 parameter (date value) the default value overrides what the user enters in the front end of the report. (a third party software).

The default value says '1/27/2017' and the user enters any other date value and the report still displays '1/27/2017'.

Please advise on how to troubleshoot and were to test. I've attempted to remove the default value all together - but the date is still coming through. Thank you.

Comment: You can view the report as XML and see if there is anything odd in parameters, like the usage of TODAY()

Comment: @JamesZ the date in SQL is correct (whatever I run my execute statement with). When I run the SSRS report (preview mode) the parameter that is displayed is what I set up as default. It's further down the line i get stuck

Comment: @JamesZ apologies for the confusion, but there is no preset default value in the database. It's a parameter i can run the execute statement 5 times with 5 different values and each time it pulls the specified value in the execute.

Comment: @JamesZ i figured it out -- its because the third party software (that was set up) has the parameter names mixed up - and its passing one value to the wrong parameter. that took a bit of hitting my head against the table but i found it.